# hibernate query combining 3 tables to get object corresponding to one table

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 3 tables named role,permission and role_permission and their corresponding pojos

```
    public class RoleTO 
{

    private int roleId;
    private String roleName;
    private int applicationId;
}
```

,

```
  public class RolePermissionsTO 
{
    private int role_permissionId;
    private int roleId;
    private int permissionId;
}
```

,

```
public class PermissionTO 
{

    private int permissionId;
    private String permission;
    private String permissionDesc;
    private int applicationId;
}
```

Now I have a method in my dao class

```
public List<PermissionTO> getPermissions(int applicationId, String roleName)throws HibernateException
{
     Session session = getCurrentSession();

    String hql = "SELECT P FROM PermissionTO P,Role R where P.applicationId=R.applicationId and P.applicationId=:applicationId and P.roleName=:roleName";
    Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
    query.setParameter("applicationId",applicationId);
    query.setParameter("roleName",roleName);

    return query.list();

}
```

But I need these three tables to be connected so that I get all the permissions in the permission class for the given application Id and the roleName linking the three tables.

Can anybody help

Answer (score 2):

SELECT P FROM PermissionTO P,Role R 
    where P.applicationId=R.applicationId 
    AND R.applicationId=:applicationId 
    AND R.roleName=:roleName";

OR

Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(PermissionTO.class, "permissionTo");
cr.createAlias("permissionTo.permissionId", "rolePermissionsTo"); // inner join by default
cr.createAlias("rolePermissionsTo.roleId", "roleTo");
cr.add(Restrictions.eq("roleTo.applicationId", applicationId)); // applicationId set value to parameter
cr.add(Restrictions.eq("roleTo.roleName", roleName));             // roleName set value to parameter

List list = cr.list();

Comment: Actually this is almost the same query I am using, This wont work in my case. What I need is a list of **PermissionTO**. I have **roleName** and **applicationId**.Using these values I need the **roleId** from **RoleTO** and then using that ID need the Permissions for that role from **RolePermissionTO** and return the corresponding **PermissionTOs**......

Answer (score 0):

I also have a similar issue, but couldnt find a solution.

but in your query I find that you should be using some constraint to connect the **RoleTO** to **RolePermissinTo** using **RoleId** and **ApplicationId** and then use this result to get the corresponding **PermissionTO** list for each given role.
I am not expert with queries, i guess this should be the logic

Comment: What do you mean by "couldn't find a solution?"